# Does WSL require some sanitary measures after shutdown with a forgotten Firefox session?

Tags: xorg, process, windows-subsystem-for-linux, maintenance

Had WSL running with an external X server (`vcxsrv`). With a Firefox window open, which I forgot, I exited the shell and then from the Windows `cmd` prompt issued `wsl --shutdown`. I then noticed that the Firefox window was still open, and tried to close it from Windows (clicking on the upper right corner **`✖`**). It took several seconds and then finally closed. From Process Explorer I saw that `vcxsrv` uses up some cpu, then shut it down normally (through `Exit`).

Could some garbage remain somewhere after all this? Can I check system integrity and do some cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have any left-overs on the side of WSL.

Firefox could have left something, although it would be very little, if anything.

You could, if worried about it, clean the Firefox cache.

You may before that enter in the Firefox address bar `about:cache` and regard
the contents of the cache with the "List Cache Entries" link.
You will also see there the cache folder under "Storage disk location",
that you can use to verify if the folder was truly cleaned out.

To clean the cache, enter menu "Options", search "cache" and you will find
"List Cache Entries". Use the "Clear Data..." button.

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot about this question!